# Correct way to write do/while and break out of?

Tags: javascript

```
var bookmark_iterator = page_element.firstChild;
do {

    // start insertion

    if (bookmark_iterator === null) {
        page_element.appendChild(div_el);
        break;
    }

    // middle insertion

    if (div_el.id < bookmark_iterator.id) {
        page_element.insertBefore(div_el, bookmark_iterator);
        break;
    }

    // end insertion

    if (bookmark_iterator === page_element.lastChild) {

        // if null will insert at the end per reference

        bookmark_iterator = null;
        page_element.insertBefore(div_el, bookmark_iterator);
        break;
    }

    // increment loop

    bookmark_iterator = bookmark_iterator.nextSibling;
} while (bookmark_iterator !== null);
```

The problem is that http://jslint.com throws an error:

```
line 643 character 19
Unexpected 'else' after disruption.
```

because I have a break statement in my if/else structure.

This makes me think that I have made a simple alphabetical insert too complicated.  Is there a simpler or better way to write this so that it passes jslint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of the `else` after those blocks.  What JSLint is trying to tell you is that it doesn't make sense to use `else` after an `if` block that transfers control out of the surrounding block statement. It's syntactically OK but it's, well, goofy. Using `else` after an `if` is useful only when flow of control proceeds out of the `if` block to subsequent code. Since you've got `break` statements in there, that will never happen.

Whether your overall logic could be improved is hard to say without more context.

Comment: I think using a while loop instead of a do while loop would have avoided the strange if/break structure.

Comment: @pure_code.com in my somewhat long experience, occasions really requiring "test at the end" loops (`do ... while`) are extremely rare.

Comment: I put up a cleaner version of the code.  It just loops over a set of divs that represent user favorites.